# MetaData Props is showing Access Denied when uploading file in AWS s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file from my Java Code to S3 and CloudFront.

```
public String uploadFile(String fileData, String fileName, String contentType, String extension){
        try {
            loggerUtils.log ("File Data" ,  fileData);
            byte[] bI = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64 ((fileData.substring (fileData.indexOf (",") + 1)).getBytes ());
            InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream (bI);
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client ();
            Region usWest02 = Region.getRegion (REGION);
            s3.setRegion (usWest02);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata ();
            metadata.setContentLength (bI.length);
            metadata.setContentType (contentType + "/" + extension.substring (1));
            metadata.setCacheControl ("public, max-age=0");
            s3.putObject (BUCKET_NAME, fileName, fis, metadata);
            s3.setObjectAcl (BUCKET_NAME, fileName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            URL s3Url = s3.getUrl(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
            s3Url.toExternalForm();
            // return s3Url.toExternalForm();
            return uploadToCloudFront (fileName, bI).toExternalForm ();
        }
        catch (Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace ();
            loggerUtils.log (exception.toString ());
        }
        return null;
    }


public URL uploadToCloudFront(String fileName, byte[] imageByteArray) {
        URL url;
        try {
            String cloudFrontURL = "************.cloudfront.net";
            url = new URL("http://"+cloudFrontURL+ "/"+ fileName);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset","UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", imageByteArray.length+"");
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.write(imageByteArray);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            connection.getResponseCode();
            if(connection.getResponseCode () == 200) { return url; } else return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I just upload the file to S3 Bucket , then the metadata attributes of my object is showing correct values.

[image]

But if I try to invoke `uploadToCloudFront()` after uploading the file to S3 as shown in the code. Then my MetaData prop are showing access denied.

[image]

Has Anyone faced similar issues with S3 and CloudFront.